Does girl scouts have a Chinese translation?
So I would like help on that please, my teacher was looking for answers and she found this
参加女童子军
(can jia nv tong zi jun)
Which when put in Google translate is, Join the Girl Scouts
(Yes I am aware that Google translate is not 100% correct)
And IF that translation is correct, is there a way to get rid of the "Join the" part?
I would really appreciate some guidance!

There were two answers, one of which seems to be a duplication. I might have accidentally deleted both answers when I converted the second answer to a comment. Now I don't see any answer. Please post again

Girl Guides:女童子军
女孩也能透过自己的版本来参与童军活动，它们分别是
Brownie Guides（小女童军）、
Girl Guides（女童子军）和
Ranger Guides（兰杰女童军）。(兰杰 phonetic loan word for ranger)
A way of militarising society, get the kids in uniform and marching!
Rishi Sunak now wants to get British 18-year-olds away from their mobile phones and into the army! If they all become drone pilots, they won't even have to put their mobiles down!


IF that translation is correct, is there a way to get rid of the "Join the" part?

Simple, just delete the verb 参加/Cānjiā/ (join), and you'll get the noun 女童子军/nǚ tóngzǐ jūn/ (Girl Scouts)
参加女童子军 -->女童子军 -->女童军

Thank you very much!

The term "女童军" (nǚ tóng jūn) is the translation for "Girl Scouts" or "Girl Guides" in mainland China, Taiwan, and Hong Kong. Here's a brief overview of its usage in these regions:
Mainland China: The term "女童军" refers to Girl Scouts. After the establishment of the People's Republic of China in 1949, organizations like the Communist Youth League and the Young Pioneers became the primary youth organizations. Contemporary scout-like activities are often organized by private commercial entities under the guise of scouting, mainly for profit through camps and outdoor activities.
Taiwan (Republic of China): The scouting movement existed in mainland China before 1949. After the government moved to Taiwan, the Scouting organization continued there. The official organization for Girl Scouts in Taiwan is called the Girl Scouts of Taiwan (中华民国女童军总会), established in 1958 and renamed in 1959.
Hong Kong: The Hong Kong Girl Guides Association (HKGGA) was established in 1916 and became an official member of the World Association of Girl Guides and Girl Scouts in 1981. The association operates independently but was originally a branch of the Girl Guides Association in London.
To address the translation issue:
"参加女童子军" (cān jiā nǚ tóng zǐ jūn) translates to "Join the Girl Scouts". The key term here is "女童军" (nǚ tóng jūn), which means "Girl Scouts" or "Girl Guides".
If you want to use just "Girl Scouts" without the "Join the" part, simply use "女童军".
Thus, the correct translation for "Girl Scouts" is "女童军".
So, for the term "参加女童子军":
"参加" means "join".
"女童子军" means "Girl Scouts".
To remove "Join the", you simply use "女童军".
